# Date object start from Monday

Tags: php, date

I currently split a date range into weeks using the following function, and it works great. The only probelm is the week starts from Sunday. Is there a way of modifying it so it starts from Monday?

```
    $start = new DateTime('2014-10-01');
    $end = new DateTime('2014-10-31 23:59');
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $dateRange = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    $weekNumber = 1;
    $weeks = array();
    foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
        $weeks[$weekNumber][] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        if ($date->format('w') == 6) {
            $weekNumber++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dow = ($date->format('w') + 6) % 7;
```

`%` gives you the remainder after dividing by 7.  So, `$dow` will be 0 for Monday (not Sunday) and 6 will be Sunday (not Saturday).